# How migrate cake php 1.x versions to 3.x version

Tags: php, cakephp, migration, cakephp-3.0

Anyone knows best way to migrate cacke php 1.x to 3.x .
Because i see the mejor changes in this two version.
And upgrade shell available 1.x to 2.x and 2.x to 3.x .

Comment: bake new app using current db and logic.

Comment: When I did my conversion, I ran the update scripts to get one version, and baked it based on the database to get another version, and did a (tedious) visual merge between the two versions to copy over critical bits of business logic.

Comment: IMHO the most important step is to first learn working with CakePHP 3, to the point where you can easily develop robust applications from scratch. Without that knowledge, you'll just stumble around in the dark. Once you're familiar with CakePHP 3, many questions regarding upgrading will already have solved themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You can run the upgrade script from 1.x to 2.x and then from 2.x to 3.x.
[1.x to 2.x upgrade](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/upgrade-shell.html#upgrade-shell) and
[2.x to 3.x upgrade](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/upgrade-tool.html).

Comment: I'm not sure that "just" is justified here; there's still likely to be lots of manual work to be done after running the upgrade scripts.